# netlogo turtle search function getting stuck in loop Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent

I have a search function for turtles to search out 'preferred patches' in a straight line in front of themselves for a set distance. I create the array of patches they search through using a loop. The code often gets stuck in the loop (I think!). I'm not sure why this happens... I want to code to tell the turtles to search through the patches for a preferred patch, have a 70% chance of landing on one of them, if not land on a random patch in the search area. If no preferred patches exist land on any patch in the search area.

The turtles don't always move, so there is obviously something very wrong with my code.

```
let move-distance random 20
loop [set search-area (patch-set patch-ahead move-distance)
set move-distance move-distance - 1
if move-distance = 1 [stop]]
let preferred-patches search-area with [flight-tendency = 0.05]
ifelse any? preferred-patches [
ifelse random-float 1 < 0.7 [
  set target one-of top-patches move-to target] 
[set target one-of other-patch move-to target]]
[set target one-of other-patch move-to target]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random 20` might return 0 or 1, and then the first thing you do to `move-distance` inside the loop is subtract 1 from it, so the `move-distance = 1` check will fail because it's already below 1.

Try replacing `move-distance = 1` with `move-distance <= 1`, and/or replace `random 20` with `2 + random 18`.